# How to change a drop-down list into a text-box on a selection in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have a drop-down list, and I want it to change to an empty text-box when I select the `Other` option.

[image]

HTML code:

```
<select id='visit'>
    <option value='1' class='volunteer'>Romania</option>
    <option value='2' class='volunteer1'>Slovakia</option>
    <option value='3' class='volunteer2'>Belgium</option>
    <option value='4' class='volunteer3'>Other</option>
</select>
```

And this is the minimal JavaScript code to start with:

```
$('#visit').live('change', function () {
    if ((this.value) == 4) {
        alert("Other selected")
        //Code to change select list into textbox here
    }
});
```

The [JSFiddle where it can be tried is here](http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/).

How can I do this using jQuery?

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/CxV9c/6/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) in this context,

```
$(this).replaceWith('<input/>');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/)

Full code would be,

```
$('#visit').live('change', function () {
    if ((this.value) == 4) {
      $(this).replaceWith($('<input/>',{'type':'text','value':'other'}));  
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/7/)

---

It seems like a bad idea to replace the select element as everyone said,
So try to show/hide the input element based on the user's selection.

Try,

```
$("input[type=text]").hide();
$('#visit').live('change', function () {  
    $(this).next('input[type=text]').toggle((this.value) == 4)
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/10/)

Comment: `replaceWith` will remove the `select`, which may not be what the OP wants, hiding it is better. However it is just my guess.

Comment: @KingKing I too agree with that, but he particularly asked us to change the select element as a input element

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Can you please explain how to replace textbox with dropdownlist ?

Comment: @vivek could you figure out how to replace textbook with dropdown list?

Answer (score 3):

Use `on()` as `live` is deprecated. You have to do it like this:

```
if ($(this).val() == 4) {
    alert("Other selected")

    //Code to change select list into textbox here
    $('#txt').show();
}
else
    $('#txt').hide();
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/2YRBJ/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this:

```
$('#visit').live('change', function () {
    if ((this.value) == 4) {
        $(this).replaceWith($("<input/>",{type:"text"}));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[type=text]").hide();
$('#visit').live('change', function () {
    if ((this.value) == 4) {
        $("input[type=text]").show();
    }
    else {
        $("input[type=text]").hide();
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/4/)

Answer (score 2):

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/)**

Code:

```
$('#visit').live('change', function () {
    if ((this.value) == 4) {
        alert("Other selected")
        var html = "<input id='visit' type='textbox' value="
                    + 5 +" />";
        $("#visit").replaceWith(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="hide" id="myText"/>
```

And say if other selected

```
 $("#visit").hide();
 $("#myText").show();
```

You can hide `$("#myText").hide();` on load.

But replacing is bad idea. By mistake, if the user selects **other**, there is no way to get the drop down again. So if the other is selected, get a text box beside the drop box.

See [@sudharsan's Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxV9c/4/).